# Determine if a user got an association bonus in SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer, association-bonus

Is there a way to determine if a user received the association bonus on account creation?

Comment: Pretty sure the event that grants that reputation is stored in the user history table, which isn't visible on SEDE for obvious reasons.

Comment: Don't have the code in front of me, but IIRC it's recorded on the account and none of the account tables are exposed in SEDE at all. (cc @animuson)

Comment: Well, you can sum the votes users got on their posts, bounties they got, approved edits, etc, and if there's 100 rep "gap" can assume it's from the bonus. (Not simple, but probably possible)

Comment: If they have 101 rep but no posts or suggested edits?

Comment: @ChrisF Unfortunately, hat excludes everybody who got the association bonus but also made a post or a suggested edit since (or offered a bounty), e.g. me on all but one of the sites I'm active on.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, you can't. An accurate reputation query is not possible, even if you emulate the suggested edit contribution limit, the rolling lower bound of 1, and the rep cap, due to inability to see downvotes cast (also downvotes on questions need date info due to May 2011 change), complex rules for deleted and CW posts, etc., and the normal amount of error in such a query generally far exceeds 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, and after more digging, no, there is no way.